# How do a custom listview item with a radiobutton and single choice

Tags: android, listview, radio-button

I have this layout for the listview item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/backgroundTela">

  <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/tvwLvItem"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Texto"
    style="@style/lvwTexto">    
  </TextView>

  <RadioButton 
    android:id="@+id/rdbDefault"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I want that my user select just one item, how control this? For exemple him select the second item then all other itens stay unselected, and when him select other item all other item stay unselected.

SOLUTION:

Use this class in ListView Item Layout:

```
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
    private CheckedTextView _checkbox;

    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        // find checked text view
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
            View v = getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof CheckedTextView) {
                _checkbox = (CheckedTextView) v;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return _checkbox != null ? _checkbox.isChecked() : false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if (_checkbox != null) {
            _checkbox.setChecked(checked);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        if (_checkbox != null) {
            _checkbox.toggle();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you only need CheckedTextView in your Layout Item:

```
<com.developer_lib.CheckableLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimDefaultButtonMeasures"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_contato_foto"
        android:id="@+id/imvFoto"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimDefaultButtonMeasures"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimDefaultButtonMeasures"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/chlSelecao"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />
```

Finnaly your Listview will control the choice mode, for example:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/lvwHorarios"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

Comment: Have you found any solution? Can you share it? Thanks.

Comment: share ur solution pls ..

Answer (score 1):

its worked for me

Step 1:

in Custom Adapter file just declare this

**int selectedIndex = -1;**

Step 2:Single Row Custom Layout

```
   <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_list"
    android:checked="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false" />
```

Step 3:

```
  <ListView
            android:id="@+id/liststorecard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            **android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"**
            android:layout_weight="1"
          />
```

Step 4: Create Interface in Custom Adapter

```
 public void setSelectedIndex(int index)
   {
        selectedIndex = index;
    }
```

Step 5: In getview method write code

```
  if(selectedIndex == position)
   {
    holder.rblist.setChecked(true);
   }
  else
   {
    holder.rblist.setChecked(false);
   }
```

Step 6: final step set Selected Index to interface

```
liststorecard.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                storeCardAdapter.setSelectedIndex(position);
                storeCardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get your solution by following idea

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-1

you must have to write your custom adapter for your CustomListView.Hope this will work for you Enjoy