# Radio Button layout not appearing with listview/adapter in dialog

Tags: android, listview, radio-button, android-arrayadapter, android-custom-view

I'm fairly new to Android but am trying my hardest to get a handle on it. I've been researching this most of the day and I've concluded that there must be an issue with my actual adapter.

Unfortunately when I load up my dialog box I don't get the list view populating.

## **My Goal**

I want to have a dialog that appears that is a custom layout that contains a listview. This has been created and has been demonstrated to work with other adapters. When the listview appears I want one option selected automatically with the radio buttons.

## **Custom Dialog XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_main_style">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_title_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:text="Format"
        android:textColor="#020202"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dialog_top_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_title_dialog"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:background="#e4e4e4" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/format_choices_list_view"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ok_change_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_gradient_button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/dialog_top_divider"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textColor="#009261"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Nothing special here, just a reference to my custom layout and my ListView.

## Custom Listview for radio buttons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/format_radio_button"
    android:text="mp3"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Normally radio buttons need a radio group but as it's a custom layout I want to use it seems like I'd only need 1 radio button?

## Creating the Dialog and adapter

```
private void showFormatChangeDialog() {
    //TODO get the list view working in the dialog
    Dialog changeFormatDialog = new Dialog(SettingsActivity.this);
    changeFormatDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    changeFormatDialog.setContentView(R.layout.change_audio_format_dialog);
    changeFormatDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    ListView formatListView = (ListView) changeFormatDialog.findViewById(R.id.format_choices_list_view);

    AudioFormatAdapter adapter = new AudioFormatAdapter(SettingsActivity.this);
    formatListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    changeFormatDialog.show();
}
```

I create a dialog and set it to my custom dialog layout. I then get a reference to my list view and crate an adapter and set it.

## FormatAdapter

```
public class AudioFormatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    static class ViewHolder {
        RadioButton radioButton;
    }

    private String formatNames[] = {"mp3", "wav","amr"};

    public AudioFormatAdapter(Context c) {
        super(c, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View formatView = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(formatView == null) {
            formatView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view_formats_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.radioButton = (RadioButton) formatView.findViewById(R.id.format_radio_button);
            holder.radioButton.setText(formatNames[position]);

            formatView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)formatView.getTag();
        }
        return formatView;
    }
}
```

My goal here is to get a reference to  my custom list view for the radio button. I grab a reference of the radio button and set the text to my array value based on the position.

I don't seem to get any data back from this ArrayAdapter and it's been blowing my mind. I've used several `ArrayAdapter` since I started and I haven't had this trouble. When I replaced this adapter with a different one it worked. I'm not sure what the issue is here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you can better to load list view items into list or arrays and populate  a dialog ...for reference check out here http://androidlift.info/2015/12/28/alert-dialog-with-simple-listview-checkbox-radio-button/  or as for your requirement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731850/show-alertdialog-with-radiobuttons-when-click-a-listviewitem

Comment: Thank you I'll check this reference and get back to you

Comment: Unfortunately from your first link the onPrepareDialog has been deprecated and the other isn't working. I'm baffled I honestly think the problem is with my adapter. It doesn't populate even with a text field.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's fixed what I wanted and I think it came down to the adapter failing. Now I'm aware my adapter does not have a ViewHolder but it has a limit amount of options so it's ok for now.

First I needed a class that allowed a CheckableLinearLayout. This is a special type of LinearLayout that allows sections of the layout to be checked and unchecked. You simply make a new class of it and then add it to your XML file as the rootview. com.YOUR-IDENTIFIER-CLASS-NAME-OF-CHECKABLELINEARLAYOUT :) You can see it in the link below!

### Checkable Linear Layout - Found here - [How do a custom listview item with a radiobutton and single choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8426774/4502550)

After using that class I made a different adapter that was much simplier and it just seemed to work.

### Adapter

```
public class AudioFormatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private ArrayList<String> formats;

public AudioFormatAdapter(Context c){
    super(c, 0);
}


public AudioFormatAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> choices){
    super(c, 0, choices);
    formats = choices;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;

    listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view_formats_layout, parent, false);

    CheckedTextView _radioButton = (CheckedTextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.format_radio_button);
    _radioButton.setText(formats.get(position));

    return listItemView;
}
}
```

As we can see this adapter gets a "CheckedTextView" instead of the radio button. The reason for this is that I simply needed a radio button style with some text and this gives me that.

I set the text with an arrayList that I pass to the adapter in "formats"

Finally I create the Dialog and get a reference to my list view.

### Dialog Creation with custom layout

```
private void showFormatChangeDialog(ArrayList<String> formatNames) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(SettingsActivity.this);
    View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.change_audio_format_dialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsActivity.this);
    builder.setView(dialogLayout);

    final ListView formatListView = (ListView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.format_choices_list_view);
    formatListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    final AudioFormatAdapter adapter = new AudioFormatAdapter(SettingsActivity.this, formatNames);
    formatListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    AlertDialog customDialog = builder.create();
    customDialog.show();
}
```

If you only want one of the options selected then set the mode to SINGLE_CHOICE. I make the adapter here and pass in a list of strings which are accepted as a parameter to my function. Then the dialog is created

### Conclusion

This was a rather irritating process as I think my adapter was breaking most things, I hope my trolling around the Internet and finding out bits and pieces can help someone else. Now I just need to save and store data depending on which option is selected!

I hope this helps somebody!